# Parsing an WebService URL in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, web-services

```
[Bindable]public var xmlData:Object = new Object();
    [Bindable]public var headingData:Object = new Object();   

 private function getHeadings(evt:ResultEvent):void{
          //xmlData = ObjectUtil.toString(evt.result);
            //ObjectUtil.toString(evt.result)
          xmlData = evt.result;
          headingData = xmlData.root.survey;
        }

     <mx:WebService id="srv"
                wsdl="http://domainame/Service.asmx?WSDL">
            <mx:operation name="GetClientDetails_ParameterDetails"
                    resultFormat="object"
                    result="getHeadings(event);"
                    />
        </mx:WebService>
```

I am able to parse an simple XML and create the components, but i am not able to do when i call an webService. The Method name which fetches the XML is the same.

Am i doing something wrong in receiving the XML in Flex.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with resultFormat as XML or e4x.

Comment: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_03.html